# Church Community Builder API Not Working In Template

Tags: templates, php

I am using an api from a third party developer that I can get to work outside of EE with a simple PHP include, but I can't seem to get it to work within a template.

You will see that this page (outside of EE) works and lists the events: http://discoverycolorado.dreamhosters.com/public_calendar_listing/

Here is the page where it is not working: 
http://discoverycolorado.dreamhosters.com/events

I don't think this is an API, I think it may be an EE issue or something I am not doing correctly with the PHP include. I was wondering if someone might have an idea why this might not be working?

Here is the include on the page I am trying to get this events list to show:

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/public_calendar_listing/event_search_list.php";
                           include_once($path);
                        ?>
```

Here is the file I am including on the above page:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>

   <table>
        <tbody>

<?php foreach ( $events as $event ) {

    // If there was a search, and nothing matched, return nothing
    if ($q && $event['search'] == '0') {
        } else {

    // Bring the recurring event dates back in to merge
    if (is_array($dup_events)) {    
        foreach ($dup_events as $dup_event) {
            if ($event['id'] == $dup_event['id']) {
                if ($event['date'] !== $dup_event['date']) {
                    $event['end_date'] = $dup_event['date'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ########################################
    #### Format the time and datestamps ####
    ########################################
    $start_stamp = strtotime($event['start_time']);
    $end_stamp = strtotime($event['end_time']);
    $date_stamp = strtotime($event['date']);
    if ($event['end_date']) $end_date_stamp = strtotime($event['end_date']);

    if (date('i', $start_stamp) !== '00' ) {
        $event['start_time'] = date($config['timeformat'], $start_stamp);
        } else {
            $event['start_time'] = date($config['timeformat_simplified'], $start_stamp);
            }      

    if (date('i', $end_stamp) !== '00' ) {
        $event['end_time'] = date($config['timeformat'], $end_stamp);
        } else {
            $event['end_time'] = date($config['timeformat_simplified'], $end_stamp);
            }   

    if ($event['end_date']) {
        if (date('F', $end_date_stamp) == date('F', $date_stamp)) {
            $event['end_date'] = date($config['dateformat_simplified'], $end_date_stamp);
        } else $event['end_date'] = date($config['dateformat'], $end_date_stamp);
        $event['date'] = date($config['dateformat'], $date_stamp);
    } else $event['date'] = date($config['dateformat_single'], $date_stamp);
    $event['occur'] = date('Ymd', $date_stamp);

    ?>  

           <tr><td>
           <?php if ($config['display_ccblink']) { ?>
                <a href="https://<?php echo $config['url'] . '/event_detail.php?event_id=' . $event['id'] . '&occur=' . $event['occur']; ?>" target="_blank">
                <strong><?php echo $event['name']; ?></strong></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <strong><?php echo $event['name']; ?></strong>
            <?php } ?>  
           </td></tr>

           <tr><td>Date: <?php echo $event['date'];
                    if ($event['end_date']) {
                        echo ' - ' . $event['end_date']; 
                    } ?></td></tr>
            <?php if ( $event['start_time'] !== '12' ) { ?>
                    <tr><td>Time: <?php echo $event['start_time'] . ' - ' . $event['end_time']; ?>
                <?php if ( $event['location'] ) { ?>
                        <?php echo ' (' . $event['location'] . ')'; ?></td></tr>
                <?php } ?>      
            <?php } else { ?>   
                    <tr><td>Time: <?php echo $event['start_time']; ?>
                <?php if ( $event['location'] ) { ?>    
                        <?php echo ' (' . $event['location'] . ')'; ?></td></tr>    
                <?php } ?>  

            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( $event['description'] ) { ?>
            <tr><td style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Description: <?php echo $event['description']; ?></td></tr>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($config['display_contact']) { ?>
            <tr><td>Contact: <a onclick="javascript:window.open('https://<?php echo $config['url']; ?>/app/easy_email.php?ax=create_new&individual_id=<?php echo $event['leader_id']; ?>&event_id=<?php echo $event['id']; ?>&individual_full_name=<?php echo $event['leader']; ?>','Email','scrollbars=1,width=520,height=710');return false;" href="javascript:void();" ><?php echo $event['leader']; ?></a> <?php echo $event['leader_phone']; ?></td></tr>
            <?php } ?>


        <?php // 2014/02/14 mjf include group name ?>
        <?php if ($event['group_name']) { ?>
                    <tr><td><i><?php echo $event['group_name'] ?></i></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>

            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>    

    <?php $count++;
        }
    } // end foreach $event ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<?php if ($count == 0) { ?>
        <p> No results found. </p>     
<?php }     
?>
```

Here is config file for the api:

```
  ##################################################
  #### CCB PUBLIC CALENDAR IN LIST FORMAT       ####
  #### Configuration Options                    ####
  ####                                          ####
  #### This CCB API example provided by:        ####
  #### Philip Cain <pcain@pantanochristian.org> ####
  ##################################################

  $config = array (



  #### CCB API CONFIG ####

  // Your church's CCB address (no "http://" or trailing "/")
  'url' => 'xxxxxxxx',

  // API username and password. You can create one by following the instructions here:
  // https://churchcommunity.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W490
  //
  // Make sure you enable the "public_calendar_listing" service
 'username' => 'xxxxxxxx',
 'password' => 'xxxxxxx',

  #### OPTIONS ####

  // Create a link to the event in CCB
  'display_ccblink' => true,

  // Display event contact information
  'display_contact' => true,

  // Display recurring or multi-day events as a single event?
  'combine_recurring' => true,

  // Set the range for how far into the future you'd like to look
  'range' => '+3 months',

  // 2014/02/14 mjf specify groups to include in calendar
  // group names must match ccb group names exactly
  // to provide no filtering, use:
  //    'groups' => array(),
  // to filter for Congregational Life Events and AWANA events, use:
  //    'groups' => array('Congregational Life Events', 'AWANA'),
  'groups' => array(),

  #### DATE/TIME FORMATS ####

  // Main time format (default looks like "6:30am")
  'timeformat' => 'g:ia',

  // Simplified time format, used when the time is at the top of the hour (default looks like "6am")
  'timeformat_simplified' => 'ga',

  // Main date format (default looks like "May 18")
  'dateformat' => 'F j',

  // Date format for one day events (default looks like "Wednesday, May 18")
  'dateformat_single' => 'l, F j',

  // Simplified date format, used for the end date of a multi-day event       (default looks like "18")
  'dateformat_simplified' => 'j',

      );

?>
```

Comment: Seeing the code on from EE template could possibly help us figure out your problem.

Comment: sorry about that. I have included everything I am using in the description above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally threw in the towel and went with the wimpy solution. I went to my main events page and used an iframe to pull in the working page. Not elegant, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To answer with an aside which may indirectly help you...

Putting PHP code in templates isn't ideal. It muddies the water and can be prone to problems.

I can't help but think that you'd be better served integrating your PHP into a simple add-on.

You could quite easily take your code and wrap it in ExpressionEngine's API. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/plugins.html

A simple plugin might look like

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Event_Search {
public $return_data = "";
public function __construct()
{
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $path .= "/public_calendar_listing/event_search_list.php";
  $this->return_data = include_once($path);
  }
}
```

You would put that into `/system/expressionengine/third_party/event_search/pi.event_search.php` and call it with `{exp:event_search}`.

But if that works maybe look into developing it into a nicer add-on in which you return the data back into ExpressionEngine variables so you can build the template directly into EE.

Comment: I think I may give that a try. I have always wanted to learn how to make add-ons. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: So I did what you suggested, but I don't see the plugin show up in the plugins section. Any idea why?

Comment: I tried calling it anyway, but see what errors I get on the page: http://discoverycolorado.dreamhosters.com/events

Comment: somehow this changed overnight. Now I am not getting the errors, but it still isn't generating any results